# Watch systemd service status with systemctl

Tags: systemd, manjaro, systemctl

Is there any option that allow watching the status of a `systemd` service in real time with `systemctl`

**What I actually do:**

```bsh
systemctl status tor
```

**For example:**

```bsh
systemctl watch tor
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the `watch` command to watch the output of `systemctl status tor`:

```
watch systemctl status tor
```

You can also follow the systemd logs for the service, which may also be useful:

```
journalctl -u tor -f
```

Comment: Any way to still get colored output from `watch`? Using `-c` doesn't seem to help

Comment: Sure, you can use the `-c` option of `watch` to interpret ANSI colour sequences, and the variable `SYSTEMD_COLORS=1` to force `systemctl` to output in colour. So the command would be `watch -c SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 systemctl status tor`

Comment: Thanks for the followup, makes for a nice alias: `alias statuswatch='watch -c SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 systemctl status'`